# Issue with body.replaceText() in Google Docs for one field only

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am creating Google Doc based on a Google sheet generated from a google Form submission, and all the fields in the google doc template are well replaced using the function body.replaceText().

Now, I had to add a field, and followed the same steps, but this field is not populated with any kind of data, neither static nor from the specific cell.

here you go the part of code:

```
  body.replaceText("{Br2}",Br2);
  body.replaceText("{Curr2}",Curr2);
  body.replaceText("{OldSc2}",OldSc2);
  body.replaceText("{Sp2}",Sp2);
```

the last line is the one which is not working, even if i tried to put a direct value into {Sp2}.
I am receiving no error upon running the code.
Any help?

I tried replacing the new value with a static value and didn't work.

Comment: Need to see more of the code.  It must be a [mcve]

Comment: Plus are you sure `{Sp2}` is in your doc, no spaces no misspelling?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
function myFunction() {
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const body = doc.getBody();
  const [Br2,Curr2,OldSc2,Sp2] = [10,20,30,40];
  
  body.replaceText("{Br2}",Br2);
  body.replaceText("{Curr2}",Curr2);
  body.replaceText("{OldSc2}",OldSc2);
  body.replaceText("{Sp2}",Sp2);
}
```

Before replacement:

{Br2}
{Curr2}
{OldSc2}
{Sp2}

after replacement:

10
20
30
40

Comment: Hello and thank you,
it seems that the original value was not written properly in the template document file.
thank you all.